# No-duplicate collection without iterator allocation

Tags: java, memory-efficiency

**Problem**

I need a collection with non-duplicate values minimising memory allocation during access operations. I am prepared to compromise with a slight decrease of performance to make up for the improved "garbage generation".

**Solutions Considered (including discarded ones for reference)**

1. **Extend ArrayList** to include a check on *add(E e)* for duplicates and do nothing if value exists. (this may include other methods too)
2. **Use HashSet (discarded)** - iteration of elements causes instantiation of a new Iterator which defeats the requirement of minimal memory allocation during access.
3. **Convert HashSet to ArrayList (discarded)** - creates more memory allocaiton than HashSet iteration.

**Question**

*Is the extention of ArrayList to reject duplicate values a sensible way to achieve non-duplicate collection with minimal memory allocation? Are there alternative methods I should consider?*

**Notes**

Most advised solutions to eliminate duplicates in ArrayList I have seen refer to using HashSet or other object instantiation which defeat my minimal memory allocation requirement. The only implementation I can think of is a basic "for iteration" of the ArrayList checking equality of the added value against each existing element.

```
Class NonDuplicateList extends ArrayList{
    @Override
    boolean add(E e){
        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++){
            if(this.get(i).equals(e)
                return false;
        }
        return super.add(e);
    }
}
```

For completion this question is being posted on gamedev stackexchange as the game dev community is more sensitive to the subjects of memory allocation and garbage collection impact, so hopefully I won't get comments along the lines of iterator allocation memory allocation is insignificant :-)

Comment: How relevant are performance and memory allocation for add and delete operations? When they aren't that important, then I might have a suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is cross-posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788397/java-no-duplicate-collection-without-iterator-allocation). Cross-posting is not allowed on StackExchange sites. If you decide to delete the other question, we could reopen this one.

Comment: Thanks - this can be closed or even deleted as StackOverflow is more appropriate for this question.